# simultaneously change all input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I clear (i.e. set to "") all the input values at once?

```
<div id="hidden-inputs">
  <input type="hidden" value="9013 NE Hwy 99" id="adderss_copy" name="adderss_copy">
  <input type="hidden" value="Vancouver" id="city_copy" name="city_copy">
  <input type="hidden" value="WA" id="states_id_copy" name="states_id_copy">
  <input type="hidden" value="98665" id="zipcode" name="zipcode">
  <input type="hidden" value="Clark County" id="county" name="county">
  <input type="hidden" value="US" id="country" name="country">
  <input type="hidden" value="45.687949" id="latitude" name="latitude">
  <input type="hidden" value="-122.659134" id="longitude" name="longitude">
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="timezone" name="timezone">
</div>
```

I've unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
$('#hidden-inputs').find(':input').val('');
$('#hidden-inputs :input').val('');
```

Comment: Your existing code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/4psGx/

Comment: I've successfully changed everything! Make you you are using `$(document).ready` or your code is at the end before you close body http://jsfiddle.net/Pzu6w/

Comment: A better example: http://jsfiddle.net/A7mMx/

Comment: @JasonP.  It wasn't working, but it must have been operator error (i.e. me).

Comment: @JasonP  I originally thought I would need to resort to `each()`, but evidently not.  Any advantage to doing so?

Comment: The `each()` in my fiddle is just to iterate them and print out the values. You don't need to iterate (jQuery will internally) to set the values all to the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

Wrap your code in [DOM  Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#hidden-inputs input').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#hidden-inputs input').val('');
```

Comment: @TusharGupta - ID selector is parent div.

Comment: i mean before you said that you don't need id selector now you write same as my code ?

Comment: Ahh. Ok, you think that I copied yours? You are wrong. I didn't see that you answered until you mentioned this. I edited mine because mine was slightly incorrect initially. Unfortunately, you seem to be emotionally troubled by this (your problem, not mine).

Comment: no you not copied i know man .Just keep your eyes open when u start reading question .

Comment: Ok Mr jQuery helping overlord.